# Trascendental extension over the complex field

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let t be a variable and consider the extension over $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{C}(t)/\mathbb{C}(t^{12})$. I have already proven that it's a Galois extension. I want to find the Galois group. I know it must have order since since the irreducible over $\mathbb{C}(t)$ is $x^{12}-t^{12}$. Now this gives me a lot of options with groups of order 12. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Let $u$ be $t^{12}$, then we consider the extension $\Bbb C(t)$ of $\Bbb C(u)$, where $t$ has the minimal polynomial $T^{12}-u$. It is a radical extension. If an automorphism $f$ maps $t$ to $f(t)$, which are the possible values for $f(t)$ (or for $f(t)/t$)?

Comment: The roots are of the form $\zeta^it$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $12$th root of unity and $i=0,1,\ldots,11$, and since the extension is simple, completely determined by what happens to $t$.